# C#: Validate an XML string against Schemas. .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, xml, schema

C# VB.NET 2.0

I have XML string object being sent to me. I have the location of the schemas (5 of them) that I need to validate this XML against.

Most of the examples I see are .net 3.5, but not many on 2.0.

The XML String does NOT Declare what schemas to use, it only has the namespaces on a good handful of elements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [XmlSchemaSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.aspx).